# PHPUnit Class not found

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

**Folder structure**

/app/lib/Helper.php

/tests/HelperTest.php

/vendor/autoload.php

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Datapark\\LPS\\": "app/"
        }
     },

     "autoload-dev": {
         "psr-4": {
             "Datapark\\LPS\\Tests\\": "tests/"
          }
     },
}
```

**Helper.php**

```
<?php

namespace lib;

class Helper
{   
    public function array_get($array, $key, $default = null)
    {
        // code
    } 
}
```

**HelperTest.php**

```
<?php

use lib\Helper;

class HelperTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test_array_get()
    {
        $helper = new Helper();

    }
}
```

**Command I run on the Server**
[Debian 8 / PHP7]

> phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php tests

**Error I get**

> 1) HelperTest::test_array_get
>
> Error: Class 'lib\Helper' not found

lib\Helper is loaded via namespace and my IDE (PhpStorm) also recognize it.
Struggling around already a few hours and don't get it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your autoload configuration says:

```
        "Datapark\\LPS\\": "app/"
```

Which means something like:

> classes in `app` directory have `Datapark\LPS\` namespace prefix.

So as an example class in file `app/lib/Helper.php` should have namespace `Datapark\LPS\lib`. Therefore you need to change namespace declaration for `Helper` class to:

```
namespace Datapark\LPS\lib;
```

And there is similar issue for your test folder.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that when I run:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit tests
```

then my tests started to work